# calculate weight for ups shipping

Tags: php, ups

I want to calculate weight of a product that needs to be shipped via ups.

for using ups api we need weight,length,width,height.

Now for example product is business card with size 4" x 3" and quantity is 50.

With only the above info for business card , can I get the rate from UPS?

I am using php to integrate ups api.

Any suggestions?

Sorry I forget,  paper is 14pt.

Comment: From the data supplied, no you can't calculate the weight.  For that, you'd need to know the weight density somehow, whether in ounces (or grams) per card or per cubic inch.

Comment: And the weight of the shipping material.

Comment: Estimate - UPS re-weighs every package and makes adjustments anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a matter of asking those in charge of packaging this product to provide these details. You'll then need to place the various rules in your application, i.e., if quantity order is > 100 and < 200, such and such type of packing will be used, which has a weight of... etc., and calculate from there. Your business should also be aware that sometimes exceptions occur and the final shipping cost may be greater than what the customer was charged during checkout. In these cases, the company will have to eat these overages.